# How to obtain a description of a Java exception in C++ when using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I would like to determine what exception has been thrown by a Java function when calling that function from C++ code using JNI.  I have the following code that catches the Java exception:

```
JNIEnv * pEnv; // assume this is properly initialized
jclass javaClass; // ditto
jmethodID javaFunction; // ditto
pEnv->CallStaticVoidMethod(javaClass, javaFunction);
jthrowable exc;
if(exc = pEnv->ExceptionOccurred())
{
    pEnv->ExceptionClear();
}
```

I do not know how to obtain descriptive information about the Java exception within this C++ code.  Can somebody help?

Comment: If all you need is to output this information to stderr for debugging purposes, you can use ExceptionDescribe() convenience method.

Comment: That seems to do nothing in C++.  In my case, the C++ is the executable, and the Java is loaded in the context of the running C++ application.

Comment: It does exactly the same thing as `exc.printStackTrace()`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have omitted calling `ExceptionCheck()` after each JNI call and checking for any failed attempts to locate methods for brevity: you should add these when implementing.

First, store the exception and then acquire the Java methods necessary for obtaining information about the `Throwable`:

```
// Get the exception and clear as no
// JNI calls can be made while an exception exists.
jthrowable exception = pEnv->ExceptionOccurred();
pEnv->ExceptionClear();

jclass throwable_class = pEnv->FindClass("java/lang/Throwable");
jmethodID mid_throwable_getCause =
    pEnv->GetMethodID(throwable_class,
                      "getCause",
                      "()Ljava/lang/Throwable;");
jmethodID mid_throwable_getStackTrace =
    pEnv->GetMethodID(throwable_class,
                      "getStackTrace",
                      "()[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;");
jmethodID mid_throwable_toString =
    pEnv->GetMethodID(throwable_class,
                      "toString",
                      "()Ljava/lang/String;");

jclass frame_class = pEnv->FindClass("java/lang/StackTraceElement");
jmethodID mid_frame_toString =
    pEnv->GetMethodID(frame_class,
                      "toString",
                      "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Second, recursively construct the error message (you may want to modify this):

```
std::string error_msg; // Could use ostringstream instead.

_append_exception_trace_messages(*pEnv,
                                 error_msg,
                                 exception,
                                 mid_throwable_getCause,
                                 mid_throwable_getStackTrace,
                                 mid_throwable_toString,
                                 mid_frame_toString);

void _append_exception_trace_messages(
                        JNIEnv&      a_jni_env,
                        std::string& a_error_msg,
                        jthrowable   a_exception,
                        jmethodID    a_mid_throwable_getCause,
                        jmethodID    a_mid_throwable_getStackTrace,
                        jmethodID    a_mid_throwable_toString,
                        jmethodID    a_mid_frame_toString)
{
    // Get the array of StackTraceElements.
    jobjectArray frames =
        (jobjectArray) a_jni_env.CallObjectMethod(
                                        a_exception,
                                        a_mid_throwable_getStackTrace);
    jsize frames_length = a_jni_env.GetArrayLength(frames);

    // Add Throwable.toString() before descending
    // stack trace messages.
    if (0 != frames)
    {
        jstring msg_obj =
            (jstring) a_jni_env.CallObjectMethod(a_exception,
                                                 a_mid_throwable_toString);
        const char* msg_str = a_jni_env.GetStringUTFChars(msg_obj, 0);

        // If this is not the top-of-the-trace then
        // this is a cause.
        if (!a_error_msg.empty())
        {
            a_error_msg += "\nCaused by: ";
            a_error_msg += msg_str;
        }
        else
        {
            a_error_msg = msg_str;
        }

        a_jni_env.ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg_obj, msg_str);
        a_jni_env.DeleteLocalRef(msg_obj);
    }

    // Append stack trace messages if there are any.
    if (frames_length > 0)
    {
        jsize i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < frames_length; i++)
        {
            // Get the string returned from the 'toString()'
            // method of the next frame and append it to
            // the error message.
            jobject frame = a_jni_env.GetObjectArrayElement(frames, i);
            jstring msg_obj =
                (jstring) a_jni_env.CallObjectMethod(frame,
                                                     a_mid_frame_toString);

            const char* msg_str = a_jni_env.GetStringUTFChars(msg_obj, 0);

            a_error_msg += "\n    ";
            a_error_msg += msg_str;

            a_jni_env.ReleaseStringUTFChars(msg_obj, msg_str);
            a_jni_env.DeleteLocalRef(msg_obj);
            a_jni_env.DeleteLocalRef(frame);
        }
    }

    // If 'a_exception' has a cause then append the
    // stack trace messages from the cause.
    if (0 != frames)
    {
        jthrowable cause = 
            (jthrowable) a_jni_env.CallObjectMethod(
                            a_exception,
                            a_mid_throwable_getCause);
        if (0 != cause)
        {
            _append_exception_trace_messages(a_jni_env,
                                             a_error_msg, 
                                             cause,
                                             a_mid_throwable_getCause,
                                             a_mid_throwable_getStackTrace,
                                             a_mid_throwable_toString,
                                             a_mid_frame_toString);
        }
    }
}
```

I copied this from code I wrote a few years ago (modified to eliminate boiler plate `ExceptionCheck()`s), but I did not compile what I have posted but the general approach is hopefully clear.

Comment: Excellent, thanks.  I'll build this in over the next day or two and then mark this as the answer.  Too bad JNI doesn't provide a function to take care of all that automatically - a weakness.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum, there may be a better way but that is the only way I could find. It is quite verbose (even more so with the continual `ExceptionCheck()`s) to say the least.

Comment: Your code works as-is without a single change.  Thank you.  (I am adding the safety checks, etc.)

Comment: I'm just getting to grips with JNI and this was really useful, thanks. One query - could someone explain why a `DeleteLocalRef()` isn't required on the result of `getCause()` at the end of the code? Assuming it's non-`NULL` of course.

Comment: @hmjd absolutely perfect description

Comment: Shouldn't we also delete the local refs to exceptions/causes and the entire frames array?

Answer (score 6):

If you are just interested in the stack trace of the exception you can:

```
if (env->ExceptionOccurred()) // check if an exception occurred
{
    env->ExceptionDescribe(); // print the stack trace          
}
```

Comment: Where does is print it to, though? Proper implementation should return a string that I can include into my long and into a bug report.

Comment: You are right @VioletGiraffe it is kind of a disadvantage, that these functions do not return strings. I had this in the normal console output of my application, as far as I remember. I did not configure or redirect my console output. Was just the standard setting in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way out of this is to declare the JNI method to throw all possible exceptions, then:

```
jthrowable throwable = ExceptionOccurred(env);
if (throwable != NULL)
   Throw(env, throwable);
```

and let your Java code deal with it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this even if the Java code has completely exited - i.e., this is a C++ executable that calls a single Java function, which exits with the exception?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Of course not. If there is no calling Java code it can't deal with the exception.

Comment: Hence, the reason for my question.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum If this refers to your original question, it doesn't contain the information that there is no surrounding Java context. If it refers to the question in your comment above, I've answered it.

Comment: I think this makes it fairly clear: "I would like to determine what exception has been thrown by a Java function when calling that function from C++ code using JNI."  This doesn't say that the C++ function was, in turn, called by *another* Java function.  Though I can see how one could imagine the opposite.