# Does jni::ExceptionDescribe implicitily clear the exception trace of the JNI environment object?

Tags: java, c++, exception, jvm, java-native-interface

I tried to implement some kind of exception handling

At first i called 
   `jni::ExceptionDescribe()`

after that i used the implementation of

[How to obtain a description of a Java exception in C++ when using JNI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408972/how-to-obtain-a-description-of-a-java-exception-in-c-when-using-jni)

which i just named for simplicity `printStackTrace()`and which completely works fine 
.

My problem is that i can not use them in combination like this.

some c++ code

```
void aCppMethod() {

     jni::ExceptionDescribe(); //Works
     printStackTrace(); // No stack trace avaiable because JNI Env does not hold any exception

}
```

but

```
void aCppMethod() {
  // jni::ExceptionDescribe(); //commented out
  printStackTrace(); // Works, where printStackeTrace just prints the Exception into a single log file

    }
```

My question is does `jni::ExceptionDescribe()` implicitely deletes the exception from the Java Environment object and is there a simple possibility to use both function in a simple sequence.

Or much more better. Is there any hook, or overriding mechanism to enhance or change the behaviour of `jni::ExceptionDescribe()`

The reason i need both behaviours, is because i want to use the appropriate C++ Code as simple Windows Executable and also as a DLL.

Comment: Thx. Yes this bug seems to be a reason. I am using JDK and JRE 1.7  so it should not occure. I will investigate it further.

Comment: @Filip_Bulovic maybe they closed it because there is no need to hold the trace than for more than just one call. I would advise you to remove your comment and turn it into an answer. And i have to ask the "ORACLE" concerning this issue.

Comment: Whatever reason they had for closing it should have been documented properly in the report.

Comment: @EJP FilipBulovic just gave me the idea to compare OpenJDK and my current JDK/JRE. And if there is any difference in behaviour i should try to reopen the ticket.. I think i will try that. Thx for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently described behaviour was reported 18 years ago on Windows, please check [here](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4067541). Then with explanation "it looks like addressed" bug was closed during 2002. What you are describing looks very similar to mentioned bug.

Comment: Reproduced yet by me. But i think it is just closed and not fixed. But for me it is no problem to implement a work arround! But maybe i can open again a ticket when i am sure that my code does not produce this issue! Thx. By the way the bug is half as old as me. So maybe i have to better check my code again. But i am pretty sure that i made no mistake.

Comment: @Diversity on one side we have "it is not bug it is by design" and on another "it looks like addressed" and you suppose to waste days figuring out what is going on.

Comment: @[Filip Bulovic] yes right. I think your are completely right. This behaviour is just a design issue. The more i think about it, the more it makes more sense. The question is: for how many exception describe calls should the jvm hold the stack trace. And the answer is just 1. But in this case jni::ExceptionClear makes no sense

Comment: Is this behaviour declared or explained within any official specifiation or documentation. This would be good for the SO conversation. Do you have any hints

Comment: @FilipBulovic On a third side we also have it closed as 'cannot reproduce'. All pretty bizarre.

Comment: @EJP don't understand your comment. What did you close. The bug mentioned by Filip or my question?

Comment: Within evaluation we can see "A third option: Change the spec to say ExceptionDescribe clears the exception." by Sheng Liang, he was lead developer on the original JVM. Doing web search on his name and ExceptionDescribe will return other similar bugs like JDK-4973054

Comment: @EJP please check JDK-4973054 and comment by Kumar Srinivasan

Comment: i think i can simply reproduce the problem. Will give you all precompile and runtime conditions within the next 2 days. Seems that the bug isn't solveld.

Comment: @FilipBulovic, EJP are you JVM developers, engineers? Appreciate the conversation with you

Comment: @Diversity likewise, no I am not JVM developer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81142/discussion-between-diversity-and-filip-bulovic).

Comment: @FilipBulovic  Where did you get 'it is not bug it is by design' from? What does JDK-4973054 have to do with it? And what comments by Kumar Srinivasan are you talking about?

Comment: @Diversity I didn't close anything. I'm just quoting from the bug cited in this answer. It was closed as 'cannot reproduce'. So it says two mutually contradictory things: 'cannot reproduce' and 'addressed'.

Comment: @EJP how to reopen a ticket at Oracle, No I think i could do that., But do you think it is worth!?

Comment: *Is* it a bug? It's documented in the Liang JNI book, although not in the JNI Specification. @Diversity

Answer (score 2):

According to Shen Liang, *The Java Native Interface,* Addison Wesley 1999, p. 211:

> This function has the side effect of clearing the pending exception.

Comment: That corresponds his suggestion on JDK-4067541 to change spec, JDK 7 spec omits that behavior [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5234 ]